# Using InMemoryEvaluatorHook with TPU throws exception

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator, tpu

I tried using an InMemoryEvaluatorHook with a TPUEstimator to get validation statistics while training my model. Using a loop of `estimator.train()` and `estimator.evaluate()` was too expensive as it rebuilt the graph every epoch, rather than trying to reuse it (as referenced in this issue: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/13895). This is the basic code I use:

```
estimator = tf.contrib.tpu.TPUEstimator(
    model_fn=model_fn,
    config=run_config,
    use_tpu=True,
    train_batch_size=self.batch_size,
    eval_batch_size=self.batch_size,
    predict_batch_size=self.batch_size,
    params={})

train_fn = lambda params: input_fn(
    'train', self.data_dir, batch_size=params['batch_size'], train=True)
val_fn = lambda params: input_fn(
    'validation',
    self.data_dir,
    batch_size=params['batch_size'],
    train=False)
train_hook = tf.contrib.estimator.InMemoryEvaluatorHook(
    estimator,
    val_fn,
    steps=self.steps_per_val_epoch,
    every_n_iter=self.steps_per_epoch)
estimator.train(
    input_fn=train_fn,
    steps=self.steps_per_epoch * self.max_num_training_epochs,
    hooks=[
        train_hook,
    ])
```

This resulted in the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dev/google_communicator/worker.py", line 160, in <module>
    main()
  File "dev/google_communicator/worker.py", line 133, in main
    results = evaluator.eval(inputs, outputs)
  File "/darch/deep_architect/contrib/misc/evaluators/tensorflow/tpu_estimator_classification.py", line 278, in eval
    train_hook,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/tpu/python/tpu/tpu_estimator.py", line 2409, in train
    rendezvous.raise_errors()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/tpu/python/tpu/error_handling.py", line 128, in raise_errors
    six.reraise(typ, value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/tpu/python/tpu/tpu_estimator.py", line 2403, in train
    saving_listeners=saving_listeners
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 354, in train
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1207, in _train_model
    return self._train_model_default(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1241, in _train_model_default
    saving_listeners)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1468, in _train_with_estimator_spec
    log_step_count_steps=log_step_count_steps) as mon_sess:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 504, in MonitoredTrainingSession
    stop_grace_period_secs=stop_grace_period_secs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 921, in __init__
    stop_grace_period_secs=stop_grace_period_secs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 631, in __init__
    h.begin()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/estimator/python/estimator/hooks.py", line 135, in begin
    self._input_fn, self._hooks, checkpoint_path=None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1484, in _evaluate_build_graph
    self._call_model_fn_eval(input_fn, self.config))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1520, in _call_model_fn_eval
    features, labels, model_fn_lib.ModeKeys.EVAL, config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/tpu/python/tpu/tpu_estimator.py", line 2195, in _call_model_fn
    features, labels, mode, config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1195, in _call_model_fn
    model_fn_results = self._model_fn(features=features, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/tpu/python/tpu/tpu_estimator.py", line 2631, in _model_fn
    rendezvous=self._rendezvous[mode]),
KeyError: 'eval'
```

Is there a better way to get validation statistics every epochs with TPUs? If not, how are you supposed to do validation?

**Edit**: I seemed to have gotten past this error by running `estimator.train()` and `estimator.evaluate()` for one step without the hook, and then running the full training with the hook. Unfortunately, after the first evaluation, there is an error with restarting training:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dev/google_communicator/worker.py", line 160, in <module>
    main()
  File "dev/google_communicator/worker.py", line 133, in main
    results = evaluator.eval(inputs, outputs)
  File "/darch/deep_architect/contrib/misc/evaluators/tensorflow/tpu_estimator_classification.py", line 329, in eval
    train_hook,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/tpu/python/tpu/tpu_estimator.py", line 2409, in train
    rendezvous.raise_errors()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/tpu/python/tpu/error_handling.py", line 128, in raise_errors
    six.reraise(typ, value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/tpu/python/tpu/tpu_estimator.py", line 2403, in train
    saving_listeners=saving_listeners
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 354, in train
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1207, in _train_model
    return self._train_model_default(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1241, in _train_model_default
    saving_listeners)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1471, in _train_with_estimator_spec
    _, loss = mon_sess.run([estimator_spec.train_op, estimator_spec.loss])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 671, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1156, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1255, in run
    raise six.reraise(*original_exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1240, in run
    return self._sess.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1312, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1076, in run
    return self._sess.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 929, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1152, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1328, in _do_run
    run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1348, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: The TPU system has not been initialized.
         [[{{node TPUReplicate/_compile/_14248540389241865347/_28}} = TPUCompile[NumDynamicShapes=0, Tguaranteed_constants=[], function=cluster_18378946049549366873_f15n_0[], metadata="\n\006\010...6\323\352L", num_computations=1, _device="/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](^cluster/control_before/_0)]]
         [[{{node tpu_compile_succeeded_assert/_1897752282630996029/_29_G679}} = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:2", send_device="/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device_incarnation=2337451129362726278, tensor_name="edge_174_tpu_compile_succeeded_assert/_1897752282630996029/_29", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:2"]()]]
```

To clarify, the following things happen before the error is thrown: the two initializing train and evaluate calls to the estimator, training for one epoch, evaluating on the validation set. When the estimator tries to restart training, this exception is thrown.

This open issue might be relevant: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensor2tensor/issues/1202

Comment: This looks like it might have something to do with the tensorflow and python versions. Maybe 2.7 has some deprecated packages? What is your tf version?

Comment: I was using 1.12